# Select inboxes in different outlook accounts

Tags: vba, outlook

How can I select the inbox of my secondary outlook account? The code below should work. But no matter if I choose account 1 or 2 (by changing the index in the `outlookApp.Session.Accounts.Item(.)` line), it still sets the `Fldr` to my first account. I know it's doing this because the message box always says 'Searched 4 items' even though there's more than four items in my secondary email.

```
Sub find_email2()

  Dim outlookApp
  Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim oAccount As Account
  Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim olMail As Variant
  Dim myTasks
  Dim sir() As String
  Dim attachmentFileName As String

  Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set oAccount = outlookApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2) ''' makes no difference if this is 1 or 2

  Set Fldr = oAccount.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  
  Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

  MsgBox "Searched " & myTasks.Count & " items"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same folder because `oAccount.Session` points to the same `Namespace` object even if accounts are different.

You can use either `Namespace.Stores` collection and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` (be prepared to handle errors as not all stores expose the same default folders - e.g. Public Folders store does not have an Inbox) or use `Namespace.Accounts` collection and for each `Account` use `Account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing `Account.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` to `Account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` did it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the two approaches will produce different results - the number of stores are not equal: e.g. a single Exchange account can contain multiple stores (primary mailbox, delegate mailboxes, PF store) and multiple accounts can point to the same store, e.g. if you have multiple POP3/SMTP accounts all delivering to the same store (Exchange or PST).